# Simplify class not found in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I am integrating a payment gateway Simplify in my laravel project:
https://commbank.simplify.com/commerce/docs/sdk/php

I have put the library files under my app folder:
App/simplify

and one file in which all other files were included in the App folder. Simplify.php

Code of the controller where simplify file is included:

```
include(app_path() . '/Simplify.php');
use App\Simplify;
if ( ! class_exists('Simplify')) 
    die('There is no hope!');
```

and it's results in 'there is no hope';

Comment: The `use` statement references a composer namespace, not necessarily the folder structure (although they usually match, and those rules are getting stricter). Have you added a namespace to the `Simplify.php` file?

Comment: yes i have used namespace App in the simplify.php

Comment: What if you pass the class namespace instead of a string? `class_exists(Simplify::class)`

Comment: now it gives error for other classes which are included in the simplify.php

Comment: Since, you've added the namespace `App` to `Simplify.php` class and you've put this class under `App` folder, so you don't need to `include` it anymore, as this class is already autoloaded by composer

Comment: @Haridarshan Please check the library link i have mentioned in the question. there is a file which is put outside the folder simpify named as simplify.php.
i have to integrate that file in my laravel project.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that's a single file. With some change you can easily use this with Laravel, all you will need to do is to add namespace `App\Simplify` to all the classes in **Simplify** folder and replacing all `require` or `include` with `use` statements and adding namespace `App` to `Simplify` class

Comment: ok let me try @Haridarshan

Comment: Still showing Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Class &#039;App\Simplify\Simplify_Constants&#039; not found in file UserController.php

Comment: I've made changes to this library. Download it and give it a try https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NsV4o12F-V5Z6vPBkY7gsY138eP9vR2w/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class &#039;App\Simplify\HTTP&#039; not found in file /var/www/html/wishtreedev/wishtree/app/Simplify/PaymentsApi.php on line 214

Comment: hey i had same kind of problem,
have you fond the solution?